# Unable to get dynamic text from a span id with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
            <div id="pdiv">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td class="normtxt" width="100%" colspan="2">Please answer this simple math question</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="18%" align="left" style="padding:0">
            <span id="mathq2" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">6 + 4 = </span>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
            <span id="mathans2" style="display: none;">8</span>
            <input id="mathuserans2" type="text" name="mathuserans2" value="" style="width: 100px;">
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" value="32317377" name="txtPolliD">
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

I am trying to get dynamic span text from the above html code using webdriver but getting:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"mathq2"}

I need to get the text:  ' 6 + 4 = ' from span id 'mathq2'

This text ' 6 + 4 = ' is chaning everytime page refreshes or new page loaded

I have tried xpath, id, cssselector but always getting the Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"mathq2"}

Here is my code:

```
  private static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd,90);

 try{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("mathq2")));
 }catch(org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e){
System.out.println("wait time outexception: " + e); 
  }


  wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mathq2']")).click();
  mathTxt = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mathq2']")).getText();

 //wd.findElement(By.id("mathq2")).click();
 //mathTxt = wd.findElement(By.id("mathq2")).getText();


 //mathTxt = wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pdiv span.mathq2")).getText();

 //mathTxt = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)wd).executeScript("    {document.getElementById('mathq2').innerHTML;}");
```

I have also tried javascriptexecutor 
When tried javascriptexecutor I got:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...) is null

By the way Selenium IDE is finding the element with xpath and storing the text. I export the Selenium IDE test case to Java/Junit4/Webdriver, then run it in eclipse and getting the same NoSuchElementException.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What about the id, is it dynamic?

Comment: Please share the URL of the webpage or the complete HTML code rendered

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not believe the span id is dynamic. It is always span id="mathq2". But the text ' 6 + 4 = ' is dynamic when you refresh the page or open a new page.                           The url is: http://www.timesofindia.in/

Comment: Tried this in Firefox, Chrome, IE, and Safari browsers and getting the same: NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to locate is inside an iframe. The id of that iframe is "mailroifrm12". Therefore you need to first call: `wd.switchTo().frame("mailroifrm12");` before calling findElement(...).

You cannot locate an element that is inside an iframe without switching to that frame first.